# How to block a user on your Wifi when win 10 MAC randomizer is on?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

### Question

How to block a user on your Wifi when [win 10 MAC randomizer](http://www.mathyvanhoef.com/2016/03/how-mac-address-randomization-works-on.html) is on?

### Details

Currently you manage your home/work wifi by:

- blacklisting: blocking/banning misbehaving users based on MAC
- whitelisting: allowing only certain MACs

#### Follow up Questions

1. With win 10's built in MAC address randomizer, isn't MAC blacklisting impossible now?
2. How would whitelisting even work? You ask people to not use this feature of win 10 (IMHO that's silly; they should *permit* you to manage their permissions)?

> **Aside:**
>
> You could say it has long been impossible; I agree, but now it has become much easier than it was earlier to spoof MACs, now that it is built into the OS
>
> **Note:**
>
> I'm aware that many *big* organizations issue certificates and verify the same at their router endpoints; so user management in this scenario is not affected. Small business owners or homes will not (or be able) to employ this method of Wifi network management.

Comment: 1) yes, 2) I whitelist one of my APs. I have the kids friends or whomever write down their mac, and then I go enter it in my routers firmware interface before the device can get online.

Comment: Just an idea : 1. Make a new wireless access point on your router. 2. Make it hidden. 3. Change all your devices to connect to the new access point. 4. Leave your *user* on the old access point. 5. Block all mac addresses on the old access point. Thus, the old access point will be inaccessible. However, to do this, you'll need a router that supports creation of multiple access points. You could also get this done using the guest network feature depending on you router.

Comment: Whitelisting MAC addresses is not effective if you are broadcasting the SSID, since that information (the MAC Addresses) are submitted in plain text, it is trivial to gain access to a network that is implementing MAC address filtering.

Comment: MAC address filtering is not a very effective security measure, especially when one can scan around for nearby network devices' MAC address even when not connected to the network as @Ramhound remarked.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't know this. Probably should make it an answer? with contributions from Don't Root here plz? Don't Root here plz hidden AP is security by obscurity no? Also, what is a simple alternative now MAC filtering is not effective?

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar RADIUS Authentication, you can the at that point, allow or disallow based on a MAC address